# How to add x-axis labels to every plot in a seaborn figure-level plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm using Seaborn to make a Factor Plot.

In total, I have 4 'sub plots' (and use `col_wrap =2`, so I have 2 rows, each containing 2 sub plots).  Only the 2 sub plots at the very bottom of the grid have x-axis labels (which I believe is the default).

Is it possible to configure the Factor Plot such that each of the 4 plots has x-axis labels? (I couldn't find this option in the Documentation or on StackOverflow)

**UPDATE**:

Here is the code (which generates 4 time series plots on a Factor Grid):

The dataframe (df) looks as follows:

```
Company     Date        Value
ABC         08/21/16    500
ABC         08/22/16    600
ABC         08/23/16    650
DEF         08/21/16    625
DEF         08/22/16    675
DEF         08/23/16    680
GHI         08/21/16    500
GHI         08/22/16    600
GHI         08/23/16    650
JKL         08/21/16    625
JKL         08/22/16    675
JKL         08/23/16    680


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns 

df = pd.read_csv(the_file_name.csv)

g = sns.factorplot(data=df,
                   x='Date',
                   y='Value',
                   col='Company',
                   col_wrap=2,
                   sharey=False)
g.set_xlabels('')
g.set_ylabels('product count')
g.set_xticklabels(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

You'll notice that the x-axis dates are shown on the bottom 2 plots.  I'd like for the x-axis dates to be shown on the top 2 plots as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I've added reproducible code.  Thanks in advance for taking a look.

Comment: Try using `g.fig.get_children()` to get a list of subplots which you can then modify individually, it works for `jointplot`. E.g. use `dir(g.fig.get_children()[0])` to get a list of all methods of the first subplot.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do it in Seaborn?

Comment: No, I did not find a native Seaborn solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure of a way to do this in `seaborn`, but you can play with the matplotlib `Axes` instances to do this.

For example, here we'll use [`setp`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.setp) to set the `xticklabels` to visible for all axes in the `FacetGrid` (`g`). Note that I also set the rotation here too, since seaborn would not rotate the `ticklabels` on the upper row.

Finally, I have increased the space between subplots to allow room for the tick labels using [`subplots_adjust`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns 
from io import StringIO

the_file_name = StringIO(u"""
Company,Date,Value
ABC,08/21/16,500
ABC,08/22/16,600
ABC,08/23/16,650
DEF,08/21/16,625
DEF,08/22/16,675
DEF,08/23/16,680
GHI,08/21/16,500
GHI,08/22/16,600
GHI,08/23/16,650
JKL,08/21/16,625
JKL,08/22/16,675
JKL,08/23/16,680
""")

df = pd.read_csv(the_file_name)

g = sns.factorplot(data=df,
                   x='Date',
                   y='Value',
                   col='Company',
                   col_wrap=2,
                   sharey=False)
g.set_xlabels('')
g.set_ylabels('product count')

for ax in g.axes:
    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible=True, rotation=45)

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.3)

plt.show()
```

[image]